# Get list of events attached to an element with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to retrieve a list of events attached to an element...

```
<div id="div_test">click HERE!</div>
```

This works

```
$("#div_test").click(function(e)
{
    var events_list = $._data( $(this)[0], 'events');
    console.log(events_list.click[0]);
});
```

But why this doesn't?

```
$(document).on("click", "#div_test", function(e)
{
    var events_list = $._data( $(this)[0], 'events');
    console.log(events_list.click[0]);
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nupa4jax/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is that the `click` event was not triggered on the `#div_test` element, but on the `document` element.
You can check `e.delegateTarget` for both versions to see which element triggered the `click` event:

```js
$(document).on("click", "#div_test1", function(e) {
  console.log(e.delegateTarget.nodeName);
});

$("#div_test2").click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.delegateTarget.nodeName);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div_test1">click HERE!</div>
<br /><br />
<div id="div_test2">click HERE!</div>
```

When you use `$("#div_test").click` you attach the `click` event to that specific element, and this allows you to get all the events that were attached to that element.

**However** when you use `$(document).on("click", "#div_test"` You **don't** attach a `click` event to the `#div_text` element that exists inside your `document`.
What you actually do is you attach the `click` event to your `document` element, and while the browser catch that event, jquery checks if the actual element that you clicked on is the `#div_test` element.
This allows you to "attach event" to elements that are not even created, yet.

To sum it up:

```
$(document).on("click", "#div_test", function(...
```

**IS NOT**

```
$(document).find('#div_test').on("click", function(...
```

Comment: Didn't know that! thanks. Is it possible to get the event_list for  `div` even when the event was attaced via `on`?

Comment: @Matías, check my updated answer, I think it might give you a clue :) (let me know if it isn't clear enough)

Comment: You have been very clear. I guess I have to to the same thing as jQuery does and check if the `div` was _clicked_ right?

Comment: That is an option, however - note that if the event is attached to the document, you can't get that specific event from the events that are attached to the element (since there is no event attached to him).